Looking for a source on Conrad-Gabber's results about spreading out of rigid-analytic families
Brian Conrad and Ofer Gabber have some results that were announced 9 years ago here:
https://www.ihes.fr/~abbes/Gabber/OferGabber.pdf
and there's a talk by Gabber about them here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QO6ooWdsBN8
But I haven't been able to track down any written reference for them. Does anyone know if such a thing exists?

Have you seen the results in BMS1?

I see that they prove a version of these results for their purposes. They also refer to a preprint by Conrad-Gabber with stronger results. So it sounds like a written source does exist, but may not be public.

And their results are not sufficient for you? In any case, I would guess your hypothesis is correct. I asked one of them several years ago about it and that was the status then. I’m not sure if anything has changed. I think your best bet is to ask Conrad (or Gabber) via email instead of asking on MO.
